# reading input delimited by spaces in java

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

im struggling with the below question.

Question: Input contains the number of blocks n (1 ≤ n ≤ 20) and weights of the blocks w1, …, wn (integers, 1 ≤ wi ≤ 100000) delimited by white spaces. the input should be taken from the user.

1. how should i write the input with spaces? (lets say my input for no. of blocks is n =5 and the weights of the blocks be : 2 3 55 6 33 - because n=5)
2. how should i read the input which are given with white spaces and store it in some list or array ? using what commands.

please find my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b1 = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no. of blocks: ");
    b1 = in.nextInt();
    if (b1<=20) {
        in.nextLine();
        int[] arr = new int[b1];
        for (int i=0; i<b1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a weights of ths blocks: ");
            if (arr[i]<=100000) {
          arr[i] = in.nextInt();




            }
    }
        }
```

i dont think this is the right way coz the input should be delimited with spaces..

i was thinking about the ways to proceed but couldnt come up with any solution. can u please help me our on this guys. thanks.

Comment: Please paste some code on what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: So if you were thinking about ways to proceed please show them in your question. And by the way: What kind of input? Textfile, user input or what? If the input is a text file provide an exact example of it.

Comment: ive pasted my code. kindly help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The input can be given at command line as "input1 input2 input3" (Weights separated by spaces)
2. You can use Scanner to read the input. Consider the sample code below:

Assuming the input is only integers.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 int numOfBlocks = scanner.nextInt();
 int weightArray[] = new weightArray[numOfBlocks];
 for(int i=0;i<numOfBlocks;i++)
       {
        weightArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
       }
 scanner.close();
//your logic
```

Comment: thanks.. this is easy to understand. one small query, how does it take the numbers with space as delimiter ?

Comment: The nextInt() method takes input with space as delimiter. Say your input is "1 2 3 4". int x = scanner.nextInt() stores 1, int y = scanner.nextInt() stores 2 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

There's a very easy way to read input delineated by spaces: use `string.split(delimit)`:

```
String input = "this is a test";
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
```

That'll give you an array, `tokens`, of "this", "is", "a", and "test".

Then you can convert to an int array like this:

```
int[] inputNumbers = new int[tokens.length];
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    inputNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```

Just make sure that you are sure that you have numbers as an input.

Comment: is it the same for integer also ?

Comment: @DevDev see my edit. You need to convert the strings manually.

Comment: Yep but with different patternt `\d` is appropriate.

Comment: @AlexK thanks.. this is very helpful. and easy too. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:
The user enters first the number of weights of the block and then presses enter. Afterwards he
enters all the weigths of the block in one line seperated by spaces (4 2 3 1) and then presses enter.
The check if the single values are in correct range, you have to do by yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b1 = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no. of blocks: ");
    b1 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    int[] arr = new int[b1];
    if ((b1 <= 20) && (1 >= 0)) {
        System.out.println("Enter all weights of the block seperated by spaces and then press enter:");
        String readLine = in.nextLine();
        String[] weights = readLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < b1; ++i) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(weights[i]);
        }
    }
    in.close(); //don't forget to close the resource!
}
```

Comment: If so please accept the answer. I tried it with your code so I hope you fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s[]= in.nextLine().split(" ");

        int[] a=new int[s.length];
        for(int i =0 ;i < s.length;i++){
            a[i]= Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering a 5 year old question with an accepted answer, it would be of benefit to everyone reading your answer if you could explain what your answer adds in comparison to the existing answers.